# Why $\lvert A_{n,\epsilon}\cap (-1,1)^n\rvert/2^n\rightarrow 1$?

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

From Rick Durrett, Probability Theory and Examples:

[image: measure]

**My Question:**

> Why $\lvert A_{n,\epsilon}\cap (-1,1)^n\rvert/2^n\rightarrow 1$? Mainly why this follows from WLLN?

I can do the calculation using integration over the region $A_{n,\epsilon}\cap (-1,1)^n$ using the distribution of $X_1^2+\dots+X_n^2$, but why WLLN directly implies that?

**Note:** This is theorem 2.2.3 :

[image: 2.2.3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\X{{\bf X}}$Let $\X_n$ denote the random vector $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$. Since $\X_n$ is uniformly distributed over the cube $[-1,1]^n$, the probability of $P(\X_n\in A)$ is just he Lebesgue measure of $A\cap [-1,1]^{n}$ divided by the measure of the whole cube. Therefore, 
$$\begin{align}
|A_{n,\epsilon}\cap[-1,1]^n|/2^n
&=P(\X_n\in A_{n,\epsilon})\\
&=P((1-\epsilon)\sqrt{n/3}<|\X_n|<(1+\epsilon)\sqrt{n/3})\\
&=P((1-\epsilon)^2\cdot n/3<|\X_n|^2<(1+\epsilon)^2n/3)\\
&=P((-2\epsilon+\epsilon^2)/3<(X_1^2+\dots+X_n)^2/n-1/3<(2\epsilon+\epsilon^2)/3)\\
&\le P((-2\epsilon-\epsilon^2)/3<(X_1^2+\dots+X_n)^2/n-1/3<(2\epsilon+\epsilon^2)/3)
\end{align}$$
Finally, the last probability goes to one as a direct consequence of the fact that $(X_1^2+\dots+X_n)^2/n\to {1}/3$ in probability. Indeed, the definition of $Y_n\to Y$ in probability is that
$$
\forall\delta>0,P(-\delta<Y_n-Y<\delta)\to 1\text{ as }n\to\infty
$$
so the result follows be letting $\delta=(\epsilon^2+2\epsilon)/3$.

Comment: What a silly question I asked actually. Anyway, at the end of the deduction, I think $\forall\delta>0,P(-\delta<Y_n-Y<\delta)\to 1\text{ as }n\to\infty$, since $Y_n\rightarrow_p Y\Longleftrightarrow (P(|Y_n-Y|>\delta)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\to\infty)$

Comment: You're right, I'll fix. @Stat_prob_001